# Send message as a link in Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : '<?php echo $app_id; ?>',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true
    });
};

$('a').click(sendRequest);
function sendRequest() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Check out this application!',
        title: 'Send your friends an application request',
        link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    });
    return false;
}

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

I want to send message: 'Check out this application!' this text as a link like
Check out this application! can you help me please how its possible.

Answer (score 0):

In apprequest it is not a possible to put link, if you even try it will be html encoded.

however if you prepare and request-form in fb:server-fbml, you succeed it.

for details see
 [How can I include a link in a FB app request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994833/how-can-i-include-a-link-in-a-fb-app-request/7045499#7045499)